# How to calculate the cation exchange resin capacity?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, extraction

If I have a cation exchange membrane and need to remove 2 g/L of sodium, how much resin would I need.

I used the amount of substance of $\ce{Na}$ to calculate the amount of substance of $\ce{SO3H-}$ needed for complete sodium removal. But this will not give me the correct mass since the resin is a polymer with that functional group attached. However I haven't been able to find any kind of complete structures for a cation resin.

Comment: Resins typically include a capacity label in $\mathrm{mmol/g}$, don’t they?

Comment: I bought one for a project pretty cheap so it didn't have much technical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need more sulfonic groups than sodium ions since sodium doesn't have a very good affinity for sulfonic groups.

Anyway, you can find some specs [here](http://msdssearch.dow.com/PublishedLiteratureDOWCOM/dh_0032/0901b803800326ca.pdf?filepath=liquidseps/pdfs/noreg/177-01837.pdf&fromPage=GetDoc) — figure 2. This source is using sulfonated polystyrene with various crosslink percentages and expresses the capacity in $\mathrm{mmol}_\text{sulfonic groups}/\mathrm{g}_\text{resin}$ ($1\ \mathrm{meq} = 1\ \mathrm{mmol}$).